# When I type "gur" or "fro" quickly Ubuntu brings up the search window. How do I turn that feature off?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, search

When I type "gur" or "fro" quickly Ubuntu brings up the search window in the upper left hand corner. How do I turn that feature off? It's driving me nuts. I am running Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS latest.

ETA: I installed tweak tool and disabled the desktop icons as suggested but when I type the word "from" quickly in chrome or any other app the search bar still shows.

[image]

Comment: It does it no matter what app I am in and says "type your command."

Comment: I installed tweak tool. Now what? I don't see any option in there that would be helpful.

Comment: I disabled the desktop icons but when I type the word "from" quickly in chrome or any other app the search bar still shows.

Comment: When you type in Chrome it searches the current page for the word(s) you type.

Comment: I don't understand how I am activating it though. Why would typing "gur" quickly activate it? What happens when you try it?

Comment: To close the search box in the nautilus file manager window click the magnifying glass..... Are you saying that file manager opens itself when you type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Updated Answer for Ubuntu 16.04"
To Disable the "HUD" Key, Open System Settings and Click On Keyboard....
[image: System Settings]

Then Shortcuts....
[image: Shorcuts]

Click on "Key to Show HUD" and hit [BACKSPACE] to Disable.